# Get binary data with XMLHttpRequest in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to download some binary data from my Firefox extension. When I try to set a created XMLHttpRequest to arraybuffer mode:

```
oHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();   
oHTTP.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

The error

```
InvalidStateErr
An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

is thrown.

Is there another way to download binary data in a Firefox extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must call the `open` method first.

Comment: Simple answer. But very helpful.

Comment: But webkit-based, like latest Chrome or Opera stable (Feb 25th, 2015), don't give a sheit when I place `xhr.open()` somewhere after `xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"`. Why so?

Comment: @paa, @ spaffy, Is this a bug?

Comment: how can I call `open` method first while using axios